# Q: Backing up Notes.app content (on the iCloud / OSX / iOS) for safekeep?

Tags: macos, icloud, backup, notes.app

I'm wondering, how do I back up Notes.app content on OSX so that I can safely either trash it all and restart, or do future upgrades?

(The reason I'm doing this is because OSX and iOS no longer sync Notes properly..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of your Notes.app is located in `/Users/youUserName/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes`

So to back it all up you need to copy/move everything in the directory above to another location and restore it later.

Comment: Thank you! I've copied it to safe-keep. The only additional question is - what happens when I wish to reinstate it's contents, do I just copy that place back?

Comment: Yes but you have to make sure that you're using the same version of Notes.app, I'm not sure what will happen if you're using a different version of the app.